# Printing missing files from a tuple

Tags: bash, files, find

I have a large list of tuples of files in the format:

```
A_1.txt
A_2.txt 
B_1.txt 
B_2.txt 
C_1.txt  <<
D_1.txt
D_2.txt
E_1.txt
E_2.txt
```

in a directory. As you can see, `C_2.txt` is missing from my list. 
I need to find a neat way of finding which of these files is missing their "partner", and print that file using `bash`.
I think I need to modify this :

```
x=$(pwd)
find $x -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

to include {0:1} so it only searches the first 1 character of my list, and prints how many files start with that first character.

Expected output:

```
2  A
2  B
1  C
2  D
2  E
```

or (ideal) expected output:

```
C_1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe your file list to

```
sed -n '$!N;/\(.*\)1.txt\n\12.txt/!{P;D;}'
```

This always reads a pair of lines and if it's not a pair of `something1.txt` with `something2.txt` the orphan line is printed, so it's given your "ideal expected output".

**Verbose explanation:**

- `N` appends the next line to the pattern space, so you have two lines, including the newline in between
- `/\(.*\)1.txt\n\12.txt/` is an "address", selecting whether the next command is to be executed. This could be a line number, a range, or in this case a regular expression that has to match the pattern space. `.*` can match any string and by surrounding it with `\(.*\)` we can later backreference it as `\1`. So `\n\12` means a newline, followed by the string from the beginning, followed by a `2`. Thus, we are searching for `anystring1.txt``anystring2.txt`
- The `!` after the address inverts the match, so the following is only executed if the pattern space doesn't match the expression. This is the case if the line doesn't belong to a pair.
- the `{}` form a block of commands, meaning that all commands inside are only executed if the pattern did match
- `P` prints the pattern space upto the first newline, so only the first line is printed (because we don't know whether the second could belong to a pair).
- finally `D` deletes the pattern space upto the first newline and the next cycle is started with the remaining line, which will again be tried to pair with the following one.

I hope this explanation helped you learn a bit of `sed`.
*

Comment: Hmm. I get an error: sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unterminated address regex
I tried a few different versions of this but the same thing happens. 
Even with: sed -n 'N;/\(.*\)1.txt\n\2.txt!{P;D;}' - which I think is what you meant?
Sorry, I'm not very skilled with sed!
Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: I'm sorry, the `/` terminating the address was missing. Corrected my answer and added more explanation to improve your `sed` skills! (-:

Comment: Unless you know exactly what you're doing, always use `$!N` instead of `N` - your code fails to print the last file name if it's not paired due to the fact that `N` is the equivalent of `q` when there's no more input left.

Comment: @don_crissti Of course, thank you. Edited. Although I believe you should always know what you are doing. By not knowing what you are doing, `$!N` can easily produce a script that never quits. (-:

Comment: How ? Can you post an example ?

Comment: @don_crissti Typical script to concatenate indented lines: `sed -e ':a' -e 'N;s/\n / /;ba'`. By using `$!N` this would loop forever.

Comment: lol, c'mon man, I'm talking about some _proper_ `sed` code not that nonsense... I mean, really, some `sed`  newb came up with that solution and everybody copies his code... If you write _bad code_, then _almost any `sed` command_ may cause an infinite loop. Try `sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/\n / /g'` which is the right way to do it ;)

Comment: @don_crissti You were talking about "not exactly knowing what you are doing", weren't you? (-; I just doubt that always using `$!N` is a great strategy when you are not knowing what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the file names, extract the prefix (the string before the first `_`) and check how many files start with that prefix (I used `set` but you may as well use an array and check its length).
If it's only one, print its name:

```
for f in ./*.txt; do
n=${f%%_*}
set -- "${n}"_*
[ $# -eq 1 ] && printf '%s\n' "${f}"
done
set --
```